# Styling an element with JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, styling

I am calling a function on button click, which changes the clicked element's parent container background.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-buy">
           <div onclick="SingleUpgrade(this)"></div>
       </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function SingleUpgrade(elem) {
    elem.parentElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/panel/btn_buy_pressed.png')";
}
```

css:

```
.btn-buy {
background-image: url('../img/panel/btn_buy.png');
}
```

Using the command `console.log(elem.parentElement.style.backgroundImage);` confirms me that the style has been applies, but apparently it's not changed (I still see the non-pressed button image). Why is that?

the URL is correct, infact I don't get an empty or broken image, but it remains the same (btn_buy instead of btn_buy_pressed).

Comment: Is the URL in the style correct?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7Lb2guz9/

Comment: have you tried elem.parentElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/panel/btn_buy_pressed.png')" ?

Comment: It sounds like you accidentally saved the not-pressed image over the pressed one? Or maybe it's still cached or something.

Comment: both url and path are correct...

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the reputation to comment so I am answering

The `url` in the `javascript` file should be relative to that file and not relative to the `html` file.

Comment: If you don't have the reputation needed to comment, then don't use answers to make a comment.

Comment: You're wrong. When you use JS to modify the DOM, URLs are still relative to the URL of the HTML file used to generate the initial page.